# Rails Global Variable- Update on each request from API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, global-variables, ruby-grape

I have used GRAPE gem for creating API end point.

For simple use case, let us consider that when my web service is hit, I hit a another third party REST API and I fetch few values and assign these values to one or two variables. for example variable1,variable2

These values changes frequently from the third party API and so I have to keep updating the variable values also, all is fine when using it in the API code or passing it across methods as params.

But I have few controllers where the updated variables should be taken/updated values to be taken.

Currently what I do is :

```
class Api < Grape::API     
 version 'v1'
 format :json
 helpers MyProject::Config

resources :foo do      
  get do
    variable1 = #hit third party URL
    $global_variable1 = variable1
  end
 end
end
```

In Controller:

```
 class SampleController < ApplicationController
   def method()
     some_calc = $global_variable1 + other_variable
   end
 end
```

Now this works fine, is there any better way to make use other than global variable ?
Or can we do like this :

```
Rails.application.config.variable1 = variable1
```

Which is the better way to go forward ?

I tried setting @instance variable like this in the API class, but this gives empty string when accessing it in controller methods.

```
@variable1 = ""
def self.variable1
  @variable1
end
```

and accessing it like ClassName.variable1

can any one please suggest better way forward ?

Comment: Do you use redis on your site? you could save the values using redis, it's really fast, you don't have to mess with the database and it will be accessible from everywhere

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you would create a single object to hold these parameters sometime during startup, and then have that single instance injected into each class that needs them via some form of dependency injection,  but since I am unaware of any commonly used dependency injection scheme for rails, I am suggesting these two alternatives.

Some people dislike singletons, but you could store these in a singleton class.

```
require 'singleton'

class APIParams
  include Singleton
  attr_accessor :v1, :v2
end

APIParams.instance.v1 = 3

puts APIParams.instance.v1
```

It might be overkill but you could also create a model for them and store them in your database.  This might be useful if you have several resources that need to store the same set of variables,  like an `api_key` and or token for example.

```
class APIResource < ActiveRecord::Base  
   # you probably would want some `belongs_to`, has_a relationships here to associate these with the models used in your controllers.
end
```

backed by a table with fields like

```
create_table "api_resources", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string  "name",
  t.string  "api_key",
  t.string  "token"
end
```

Comment: hey thanks for you suggestion, but I am not allowed to create any entry in DB for this. But I will try the singleton class way you mentioned. Many thanks.

Comment: Why would you not be allowed to store something in the DB?

Answer (score 1):

Global variables are a bad idea IMHO. This is more or less the same as a singleton.
How will you update the variable and who will do it? When? How will you check if expired? What if you have multiple ruby processes and they use different values?

This sounds like a good use case for a cache and a service that reads from the cache.

```
class ParameterService
  def get(parameter_name)
    if parameter is not in cache or expired
      read from external service and store in cache
    end
    return value from cache
  end
end
```

The cache could be something like Redis, a DB, Memcached.

Comment: hey thanks for your opinion, I will store in redis and then use it. Wanted to know on the options available. Thanks again I am clear now.